# SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas blocks after unlockCanvasAndPost() throws Illegal Argument Exception after turning screen off

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I have a class DrawingPanel that extends SurfaceView. It does some custom graphics stuff. It works fine most of the time, but I run in to issues if the surface is displayed and the screen turns off and back on. Sometimes, when turning the screen off, unlockCanvasAndPost() throws an IllegalArgumentException.

Then, after I turn the screen back on, the thread starts, as kicked off in the containing Fragment's onResume() method, but the call to lockCanvas blocks. Is there a way I can recover from the exception of unlockCanvasAndPost() ?

I can reproduce this on a Galaxy Nexus and a Nexus 5, but not a Galaxy S4 nor a Nexus 9.

```
public DrawingPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated()");
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged()");
    //Allows us to use invalidate() to call onDraw()
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed()");
    stopDrawingThread();
}

public void startDrawingThread() {
    Log.d(TAG, "startDrawingThread()");
    stopDrawingThread();
    m_thread = new PanelDrawThread(getHolder());
    m_thread.setRunning(true);
    m_thread.start();
}

public void stopDrawingThread() {
    Log.d(TAG, "stopDrawingThread()");
    // if we haven't started the thread before, there's nothing to stop.
    if(null != m_thread) {
        try {
            m_thread.setRunning(false);
            m_thread.join(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Thread Interrupted.", e);
        }
    }
}


private class PanelDrawThread extends Thread {

    private static final long REDRAW_FRAME_SLEEP_TIME_MILLISECONDS = 20;
    private final SurfaceHolder m_surfaceHolder;
    private boolean m_isRunning;

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        m_isRunning = run;
    }

    public PanelDrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        m_surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas = null;

        while(m_isRunning) {
            if(m_redrawRequired) {
                try {
                    Log.v(TAG, "A. Locking Canvas");
                    Log.v(TAG, "A2. Canvas Surface Valid?: " + m_surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid());
                    canvas = m_surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    Log.v(TAG, "B. Canvas Locked");
                    synchronized (m_surfaceHolder) {
                        drawGraphics(canvas);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error drawing graphics", ex);
                } finally {
                    if (canvas != null) {
                        try {
                            Log.v(TAG, "C. Unlocking Canvas");
                            m_surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                            Log.v(TAG, "D. Canvas Unlocked");

                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                            // ignore "Cannot unregister a locked buffer (ID=466)"
                            Log.e(TAG, "Illegal Argument Exception", iae);
                            canvas = null;
                        }
                    }
                    m_redrawRequired = false;
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(REDRAW_FRAME_SLEEP_TIME_MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error on sleep", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception:

```
05-19 08:22:19.855    7296-7336/my.drawing.app.android E/DrawingPanel﹕ Illegal Argument Exception
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            at android.view.Surface.nativeUnlockCanvasAndPost(Native Method)
            at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Surface.java:255)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$4.unlockCanvasAndPost(SurfaceView.java:844)
            at myapp.DrawingPanel$PanelDrawThread.run(DrawingPanel.java:181)
```

Comment: Block rendering of contents if the activity is paused, handle this with the help of a boolean value

Comment: @Triode Can you expand on this?

Comment: When teh fragment goes onPause(), I stop the drawing thread via the stopDrawingThread() method

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity